Ergodicity of Markov shift on natural numbers and his composition.
I know that Markov shift $\sigma$ define on $\Omega=\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\right\}^{\mathbb{N}_0}=\left\{\left\{\eta_i\right\}_{i=0}^{\infty}; \eta_i\in\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,n\right\} \text{ for every }i\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}$ with probability measure $P([\eta_0,\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_{n-1}])=\mu_{\eta_{n-1}}\cdot p_{\eta_{n-1}\eta_{n-2}}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_{\eta_{1}\eta_0}$, where $p_{\eta_{i}\eta_j}$ are some elements of a transition matrix $\mathbb{P}$, $\mu_{\eta_{n-1}}$ is a initial distribution and $[\eta_0,\eta_1,\ldots,\eta_{n-1}]=\left\{\{a_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}\in \Omega; a_0=\eta_0,\ldots,a_{n-1}=\eta_{n-1}\right\}$ is measure preserving and it is ergodic if the transition matrix $\mathbb{P}$ is irreducible (it means that the chain is irreducible).
Of course, the shift $\sigma$ is define as $\sigma(\eta_0,\eta_1,\eta_2,\ldots)=(\eta_1,\eta_2,\ldots)$.
Now assume Markov shift $\tilde{\sigma}$ on $\Sigma=\mathbb{N}_0^{\mathbb{N}_0}=\left\{\left\{\eta_i\right\}_{i=0}^{\infty}; \eta_i\in\mathbb{N}_0 \text{ for every }i\in\mathbb{N}_0\right\}$ and everything is the same. I can proof that the shift $\tilde{\sigma}$ is measure preserving. Moreover I can proove that $\tilde{\sigma}_{N}(\eta_0,\eta_1,\eta_2,\ldots)=(\eta_N,\eta_{N+1},\ldots)$ is measure preserving but I also need to show that $\tilde{\sigma}_{N}$ is ergodic if the transition matrix $\mathbb{P}$ is irreducible.
Somewhere I found that $\tilde{\sigma}$ is ergodic when the transition matrix $\mathbb{P}$ is irreducible. However do not understand the proof of the erodicity of $\tilde{\sigma}$. But if it is true it is also true that $\tilde{\sigma}_{N}$ is ergodic?
Any help is appreciated or some recommendation of the literature where I can find something like that.
Thank you very much.
